# How to launch particular application when Power Button is pressed twice in Android

Tags: android

> I want to launch a specific application when we power button pressed
>   twice. Atfirst I want to confirm it about possibility, if it is
>   possible then please help me how to implement it.

Comment: use broadcast receiver in your application

Comment: @Hemant would you provide code or method ?